# Installing specific version of Cordova Salesforce Plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, salesforce, cordova-plugins

I would like to install specific version of salesforce cordova plugin. But I m unable to. I tried this command to install specific version

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin#7.3.0`

I get error while doing this. How do I get to install specific version?

Answer (score 0):

you can refer https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin/releases

check proper version which one is required.

then

and then you can follow just like

cordova plugin add https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin@7.3.0

Comment: I get this error when I try installing - 

Failed to fetch plugin https://github.com/forcedotcom/SalesforceMobileSDK-CordovaPlugin@7.3.0 via registry.
Probably this is either a connection problem, or plugin spec is incorrect.

Comment: @nOObiOS    just download plugin on local file system, and try installing from your local file system path.. That would help you.